# PostgreSQL: What's the best way to find rows by two column values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql

Let's say I've got software packages and those packages have versions. Each version has its own license.

```sql
create table my_package (
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

insert into my_package (name) values
    ('a'),
    ('b'),
    ('c'),
    ('d');

create table my_version (
    my_package_id int references my_package,
    version text,
    license text
);

insert into my_version (my_package_id, version, license) values
    (1, '1.0.0', 'mit'),
    (1, '2.0.0', 'isc'),
    (1, '3.0.0', 'bsd'),
    (2, '1.0.0', 'foo'),
    (2, '2.0.0', 'bar'),
    (2, '3.0.0', 'baz'),
    (3, '1.0.0', 'aaa'),
    (3, '2.0.0', 'bbb'),
    (3, '3.0.0', 'ccc'),
    (4, '1.0.0', 'ggg'),
    (4, '2.0.0', 'qqq');
```

My problem is finding the licenses for packages where I have the versions and the names, e.g. `a: 2.0.0` and `b: 1.0.0`.

Here is what I'm currently doing.

```sql
select
    my_package.name,
    my_version.version,
    my_version.license
from
    unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b'], array['2.0.0', '1.0.0']) as t(name, version)
join my_package on t.name = my_package.name
join my_version on my_package.id = my_version.my_package_id and t.version = my_version.version;
```

That returns the result I'm expecting.

```sql
|name|version|license|
|----|-------|-------|
|a   |2.0.0  |isc    |
|b   |1.0.0  |foo    |
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way without using `unnest` and ideally subqueries in the `from` clause. My goal would be to find a query that works using JPA.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query a set of column together by wrapping them in parentheses:

```sql
select
    my_package.name,
    my_version.version,
    my_version.license
from my_package p
 join my_version v on p.id = v.my_package_id 
WHERE
 (p.name,v.version) in (('a','2.0.0'),('b','1.0.0'));
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about that. Unfortunately it looks like I won't be able to translate that into JPA. Nevertheless I believe it's the easiest query for hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is finding the licenses for packages where I have the versions and the names, e.g. a: 2.0.0 and b: 1.0.0.

I was wondering why you wouldn't just query those values in the `where` clause and wrote this reply... and just noticed the reference to JPA, which is a package I'm not familiar with. In that case, maybe this isn't helpful but figure i'd post it anyway.

```sql
select
    my_package.name,
    my_version.version,
    my_version.license
FROM my_package
INNNER JOIN my_version on my_package.id = my_version.my_package_id

WHERE my_package.name = 'a' AND my_version.version = '2.0.0' 
  OR my_package.name = 'b' AND my_version.version = '1.0.0'
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but the 'and' binds tighter than the 'or', so the implicit parenthesis are: `(my_package.name = 'a' AND my_version.version = '2.0.0') 
  OR (my_package.name = 'b' AND my_version.version = '1.0.0')`. You can test this in postgres with `select true and false or true and false` => false

Comment: Thank you! Although I might not be able to translate that directly using JPQL I might be able to use the Specification / Criteria API to make it work in the end. Good idea pointing into the right direction. In the end I will have 100s of `OR` statements.